# Why when I trying to make a function that delete books from my library I get an Error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10

> Example of book that I want to delete from the books_library  (depends on the book name (input)):

> {'Books': [{"Book's ID": {'001'}, "Book's Name": {'Avengers'}, "Book's Authors": {'Stan Lee'}, "Book's Published year": {'1938'}, "Book's Type": {'1'}, "Book's Copies": {'10'}}, {"Book's ID": {'002'}, "Book's Name": {'Spider Man'}, "Book's Authors": {'Stan Lee'}, "Book's Published year": {'1948'}, "Book's Type": {'2'}, "Book's Copies": {'15'}}]}

> The function i'm using:

```
def delete_book(book_name, books_library):
"""
A function that update the collection of books that in the library, without deleting one.
:param book_name: The name of the book to delete.
:param books_library: A collection of all the books in library
"""

for book in range(len(books_library["Books"])):
    if book_name in books_library["Books"][book]["Book's Name"]:
        print("Are you sure you want delete this book?: ")
        identifier = input()
        identifiers = ['y','n']
        while identifier not in identifiers:
            print("Please answer with y or n")
            print("Are you sure you want to delete this book?: ")
            identifier = input()
        if identifier == 'y':
            books_library["Books"][book].pop(book)
            return f"{book_name} is deleted from books library"
        ## Todo : Find a way to delete book by his name (should delete all books details)
        else:
            print(f"The book {book_name} does not exist!")
        if identifier == 'n':
            print("Canceling...")
            break
```

> The code i'm using in Main.py:

```
        if identifier == '4':  # choosing to Remove a book
           print("Which book would you like to remove?: \n")
           book_name = input()
           delete_book(book_name, books_library)
           print("The Book has deleted from library.")
```

> The Error that I get every time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\John bryce - python\FirstProject-managing book library\main.py", line 83, in 
  <module>
  delete_book(book_name, books_library)
   File "d:\John bryce - python\FirstProject-managing book library\LibraryBooks.py", 
   line 91, in delete_book
   books_library["Books"][book].pop(book)
   KeyError: 0
```

Comment: What is the structure of `books_library`?

Comment: books_library = {"Books": []} @Programmin-in-Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this:

```
{'Books': [{"Book's ID": {'001'}, "Book's Name": {'Avengers'}, "Book's Authors": {'Stan Lee'}, "Book's Published year": {'1938'}, "Book's Type": {'1'}, "Book's Copies": {'10'}}, {"Book's ID": {'002'}, "Book's Name": {'Spider Man'}, "Book's Authors": {'Stan Lee'}, "Book's Published year": {'1948'}, "Book's Type": {'2'}, "Book's Copies": {'15'}}]}
```

You're selecting 'Books' from 'books_library' dictionary.

books_library => dict

books_library['Books'] => list

books_library["Books"][book] => dict

Remember from the first line

```
for book in range(len(books_library["Books"]))
```

'book' is an integer and it's not present as a key in the dict under  books_library["Books"][book].

I think this should word

```
books_library['Books'].pop(book)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace:

```
books_library["Books"][book].pop(book)
```

By:

```
books_library["Books"].pop(book)
```

Comment: Thank you my friend!, it is work
can you explain me please the differences between this two code lines?
@Corralien

Comment: `books_library["Books"]` is your list. The `pop` method is attached to your list not to the sub dict inside.

Comment: `type(books_library["Books"][book])` returns `dict`. `type(books_library["Books"])` returns `list`. Is it clearer for you?

Comment: Yes, it's clearer now. thank you